# Understanding the output of git status with the short flag

Tags: git, terminology

```
$ git status -s
 M README
MM Rakefile
A  lib/git.rb
M  lib/simplegit.rb
?? LICENSE.txt
```

There are two columns to the output - the left-hand column indicates the status of the staging area and the right-hand column indicates the status of the working tree. So for example in that output, the README file is modified in the working directory but not yet staged, while the lib/simplegit.rb file is modified and staged. The Rakefile was modified, staged and then modified again, so there are changes to it that are both staged and unstaged.

The above is from Pro Git by Scott Chacon and Ben Straub and published by Apress.

I'm confused about the distinction between staging area and working tree. And I'll explain what I believe is to be true.

"the README file is modified in the working directory but not yet staged": We're not tracking this file. Still, Git understands that it has been modified. From the last snapshot.

"the lib/simplegit.rb file is modified and staged": after modification we've staged the file. All that is left is the commit.

"The Rakefile was modified, staged and then modified again, so there are changes to it that are both staged and unstaged.": Just like the previous file we have staged a modified file. What's next?

Comment: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format

Comment: what is the question? if you dont know what "modified" and "staged" means i suggest you read it up here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "the README file is modified in the working directory but not yet staged": We're not tracking this file. Still, Git understands that it has been modified. From the last snapshot.

No, this is wrong: specifically, the file *is* staged (and the staged copy matches the `HEAD` copy, and this makes the file *tracked*).  The tricky part with the staging-area is that it is normally mostly invisible.  This leads people down the wrong path in trying to understand how it works.

First, let's tackle some Git terminology.  There are three entities of interest at this point: the *current commit*, the *staging-area*—which actually has three names—and the *work-tree*.  The three names for the staging-area are *index*, *staging-area*, and *cache*, and these three names reflect the low quality of Linus Torvald's original choice ("index") or the enormous importance of the invisible staging-area, or both.  (I think both.)  Let's look deeper at each one:

- The current commit, which we can also name via the name `HEAD` (in all capitals<sup>1</sup>), is of course a commit—it's a snapshot of all the files that were in the staging area when you (or whoever) ran `git commit`.  This snapshot is permanent (mostly) and read-only (entirely).  Its true name is not `HEAD`—that's just a symbolic name by which we can find it right now—but rather some big ugly hash ID.  The hash ID appears random, but is in fact a cryptographic checksum of the complete contents of the commit.  That's *why* the commit can't be changed—changing anything would change the checksum, resulting in a *different* commit.

  The files stored within<sup>2</sup> the commit are also read-only.  They are stored in a special, Git-only, compressed form.  This particular compression has the nice property that if the contents of a file are the same from one commit to another, these commits all *share* the underlying compressed file-image.  That means you can commit a big file millions of times, if you like, and not use any more space than committing that file once.
- The index / staging-area / cache is this crazy almost-invisible data structure.  It contains *all the files* at all times, in the same way that a commit contains all the files.  The files in the index are also in this special compressed Git-only format.  The key difference between a file copy in the index / staging-area, and a copy in a commit, is that the index one can be *overwritten*.

  (The index also caches—hence the name "cache"—information about the work-tree, to make Git go faster.  These two facts, that the index holds all the files all ready to go into the next commit, and that it caches stuff about the work-tree, are what make `git commit` so insanely fast, compared to other similar version control systems.)
- The work-tree is the simplest of the three, but in a sense, also the one Git cares the least about.  It's where you do your work on your files.  These files are in the ordinary format that the rest of your computer programs understand.  They are the most important to *you*, but the least important to Git: a `--bare` repository has *no* work-tree, but Git can still function (in a more limited way of course).

The work-tree is the only one of these three things that you can see easily and directly.  Simply use whatever command it is that lists files or views files: there they are, plain to see.  Fortunately, commits are easy to see as well, by checking them out.

When you initially check out some particular commit—via `git checkout master` or `git checkout develop`, for instance—Git populates *both* your index / staging-area *and* you work-tree from that commit.  It sets `HEAD` to be a symbolic name for the correct hash ID.  That way, the index already has in it all the same files that are in the `HEAD` commit, and the work-tree has all the same files that are in the index.

If you modify a file in the work-tree, and then run `git add` on it, Git copies the work-tree version of that file into the index / staging-area.  Now the `HEAD` commit version and the index version differ, but the index version and the work-tree version agree with each other.

If you modify a file in the work-tree but *don't* run `git add` on it, the `HEAD` and index versions agree, but the index version disagrees with the work-tree version.

If you modify a file in the work-tree, then (1) use `git add` to copy it to the index / staging-area and (2) modify it *again*, now *all three* versions of that file differ.  This is where you will see an `MM` status.

What `git status` is doing is, in effect, running two diffs.  The first one compares `HEAD` to the index.  Whatever is different here is "staged for commit".  The second diff compares the index to the work-tree.  Whatever is different here is "not staged for commit".  That's *almost* it—we're nearly done!

Last, let's take a look at the term *tracked* as applied to files.  In Git, a file is tracked if and only if it is in the index / staging-area.  It's really that simple!  The tricky part is telling whether a file is in fact in the index, since it's normally so invisible there.

The `git status` command *compares* the index: first, it compares `HEAD` vs `index`.  Suppose some file is in both `HEAD` and `index` and has the same contents in both.  Then you won't see it here.  Likewise, you won't see it here if it's the same in the index and the work-tree.  So if the file *is* in the index, but matches both `HEAD` and work-tree versions, it's invisible.

Suppose some file *isn't* in the index.  If it's in `HEAD`, `git status` will tell you that between `HEAD` and the index, the file got deleted—a `D` in the first column of the short output.  So in that case you can tell: the file has gone away from the index, and is no longer tracked.  It won't be in the next commit.

Suppose some file *isn't* in `HEAD`, but *is* in the index.  In this case `git status` will tell you that between `HEAD` and the index, the file got *added*—an `A` in the first column of the short output.  So in that case you can tell that the file is now tracked, and will be in the next commit.

The tricky case occurs when a file is *both untracked and ignored*, because now, if the file is *not* in the `HEAD` commit (and by definition it's not in the index—we just said it was untracked), the first column can't tell you anything: it's not in either of those two entities, so Git says nothing here.  The second column *could* tell you that the index and work-tree don't match, if the file exists in the work-tree, but since you told Git that the untracked work-tree file should be ignored, `git status` won't mention it here either.

Finally, there are a few things worth mentioning:

- You *can* actually view the index.  Run `git ls-files --stage` to see a quick view of most of what is actually in the staging-area.  This is impractical in a big project, precisely because the staging-area holds a copy of *every* file—well, every file that will be committed.  That can be tens of thousands of files.  It's much more useful to view the *difference* between the `HEAD` commit and the index / staging-area, so that's what `git status` does (in the first column of `--short` output).
- You can also view the contents of a commit directly.  Run `git ls-tree -r HEAD` to see all of the committed files.  The output is similar to `git ls-files --stage`.  (It adds the Git object type name and takes away the staging number, and uses a tree structure rather than the index's flattened-tree.)  As with `git ls-files --stage` this is mainly useful for debugging Git or writing fancy new commands, not for regular work.

The key here is that `git status` summarizes the state of the three entities of interest, by comparing `HEAD` to the index, and then comparing the index to the work-tree.  The two columns show you the *differences* between them, stripped down to just a letter code and a file name.  Even though the next commit will be a snapshot of every file that is in the index / staging-area at that time, it's more useful to tell you what's *different* about that snapshot, as compared to the current snapshot, or the potential snapshot you *could* make by copying work-tree files into the index.

---

<sup>1</sup>On Windows and MacOS where opening a file named `readme.txt` opens an existing file named `README.TXT` (and vice versa), you can use lowercase, but Git has various places where it hard-codes the all-capitals `HEAD` string, so it's best to stick with that.  If you don't like typing that much, the character `@` is a synonym for `HEAD`.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, a commit stores the hash ID of a *tree* object.  The tree object stores each file's name, mode (100644 or 100755), and content-hash-ID, along with names and hash IDs for subtrees as needed.  Hence the file contents are not actually *inside* the commit, but rather laid out as *blob* objects, right alongside commit and tree objects.  This is the mechanism by which commits—and the index!—share blob objects so that however many snapshots you have of a big file, you really only have one copy in the repository database.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about what the letters means here :

https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format

If "staging area", "added" or "unmerged" are unfarmiliar to you, maybe you need to deepen your git understanding. Or maybe just stop using the `-s` flag, which is really simpler to understand.

The git pro git is really git, but you can't pick what you want to read. Read everything, in the correct order. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: I've edited the question to explain what I'm confused about.